# Looking up a map value where the key is a string inside an array. Why does this work?

Tags: javascript

The following snippet of code

```
var map = { a: 1, b: 2 },
    arr = ['a'];

console.log(map[arr]);
```

will print out `1`. Why is that? Does Javascript convert `arr` into a string before doing the lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Javascript convert `arr` into a string before doing the lookup?

[Yep.](https://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1)